# A RenderFlex overflowed by Infinity pixels on the right. when using a Row inside a Container

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
Column(
  Expanded( 
flex: 2,

        child: Container(
          height: 30,
            color: Colors.indigo,              
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
            child: Row(
            // cmainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "For more information on ABC CLICK HERE",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 10,
                      ),
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _lights = true;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
            ),
          ),
```

this section of my project returns error mentioned below any kind of help will be appreciated

```
Performing hot reload...                                               |I/flutter (26968): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════ I/flutter (26968): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout(): I/flutter (26968): RenderPointerListener object was given an infinite size during layout. I/flutter (26968): This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big as possible, but it was put I/flutter (26968): inside another render object that allows its children to pick their own size. I/flutter (26968): The nearest ancestor providing an unbounded width constraint is: RenderFlex#2821b relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE OVERFLOWING: I/flutter (26968):   creator: Row ← Padding ← ColoredBox ← ConstrainedBox ← Container ← Expanded ← Column ← _BodyBuilder I/flutter (26968):     ← MediaQuery ← LayoutId-[<_ScaffoldSlot.body>] ← CustomMultiChildLayout ← AnimatedBuilder ← ⋯ I/flutter (26968):   parentData: offset=Offset(12.0, 12.0) (can use size) I/flutter (26968):   constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=368.7, h=25.0) I/flutter (26968):  size: Size(368.7, 25.0) I/flutter (26968):   direction: horizontal I/flutter (26968):   mainAxisAlignment: start I/flutter (26968):   mainAxisSize: max I/flutter (26968):   crossAxisAlignment: center I/flutter (26968):   textDirection: ltr I/flutter (26968):   verticalDirection: down I/flutter (26968): The constraints that applied to the RenderPointerListener were: I/flutter (26968):   BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, 0.0<=h<=25.0) I/flutter (26968): The exact size it was given was: I/flutter (26968):   Size(Infinity, 25.0) I/flutter (26968): See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/box-constraints for more information. I/flutter (26968): I/flutter (26968): The relevant error-causing widget was: I/flutter (26968):   GestureDetector file:///D:/developement/task9/lib/main.dart:48:21 I/flutter (26968): I/flutter (26968): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: I/flutter (26968): #0      RenderBox.debugAssertDoesMeetConstraints.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1967:9) I/flutter (26968): #1  RenderBox.debugAssertDoesMeetConstraints (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2035:6) I/flutter (26968): #2  RenderBox.size=.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1752:7) I/flutter (26968): #3  RenderBox.size= (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1754:6) I/flutter (26968): #4      RenderPointerListener.performResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:2626:5) I/flutter (26968): #5      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:114:7) I/flutter (26968): #6      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7) I/flutter (26968):
#7      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13) I/flutter (26968): #8      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7) I/flutter (26968):
#9      RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:746:15) I/flutter (26968):
#10     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7) I/flutter (26968):
#11     RenderPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:207:11) I/flutter (26968): #12     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7) I/flutter (26968):
#13     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13) I/flutter (26968): #14     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7) I/flutter (26968):
#15     RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:266:13) I/flutter (26968): #16     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7) I/flutter (26968):
#17     RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:808:17) I/flutter (26968):
#18     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7) I/flutter (26968):
#19     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:171:11) I/flutter (26968): #20     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:480:7) I/flutter (26968):
#21     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:240:7) I/flutter (26968): #22     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:399:14) I/flutter (26968): #23     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7) I/flutter (26968):
#24     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13) I/flutter (26968): #25     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7) I/flutter (26968):
#26     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13) I/flutter (26968): #27     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1265:11) I/flutter (26968): #28     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7) I/flutter (26968):
#29     RenderPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:207:11) I/flutter (26968): #30     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7) I/flutter (26968):
#31     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13) I/flutter (26968): #32     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7) I/flutter (26968):
#33     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13) I/flutter (26968): #34     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7) I/flutter (26968):
#35     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13) I/flutter (26968): #36     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7) I/flutter (26968):
#37     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13) I/flutter (26968): #38     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7) I/flutter (26968):
#39     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13) I/flutter (26968): #40     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7) I/flutter (26968):
#41     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13) I/flutter (26968): #42     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7) I/flutter (26968):
#43     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13) I/flutter (26968): #44     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7) I/flutter (26968):
#45     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13) I/flutter (26968): #46     RenderOffstage.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3242:13) I/flutter (26968): #47     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7) I/flutter (26968):
#48     _RenderTheatre.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:700:15) I/flutter (26968):
#49     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7) I/flutter (26968):
#50     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13) I/flutter (26968): #51     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7) I/flutter (26968):
#52     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13) I/flutter (26968): #53     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7) I/flutter (26968):
#54     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13) I/flutter (26968): #55     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7) I/flutter (26968):
#56     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13) I/flutter (26968): #57     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7) I/flutter (26968):
#58     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13) I/flutter (26968): #59     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7) I/flutter (26968):
#60     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13) I/flutter (26968): #61     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7) I/flutter (26968):
#62     RenderView.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/view.dart:167:13) I/flutter (26968):
#63     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1630:7) I/flutter (26968):
#64     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:887:18) I/flutter (26968):
#65     RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:402:19) I/flutter (26968):
#66     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:865:13) I/flutter (26968):
#67     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:284:5) I/flutter (26968):
#68     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1074:15) I/flutter (26968): #69     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1013:9) I/flutter (26968):
#70     SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:822:7) I/flutter (26968): (elided 4 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, and dart:async-patch) I/flutter (26968): I/flutter (26968): The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderPointerListener#a0435 relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE: I/flutter (26968):   creator: _PointerListener ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector ← GestureDetector ← I/flutter (26968):     Row ← Padding ← ColoredBox ← ConstrainedBox ← Container ← Expanded ← Column ← ⋯ I/flutter (26968):   parentData: <none> (can use size) I/flutter (26968):   constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, 0.0<=h<=25.0) I/flutter (26968):   size: Size(Infinity, 25.0) I/flutter (26968):   behavior: translucent I/flutter (26968):   listeners: down I/flutter (26968): This RenderObject has no descendants. I/flutter (26968): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════ I/flutter (26968): Another exception was thrown: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler object was given an infinite size during layout. I/flutter (26968): Another exception was thrown: RenderPointerListener object was given an infinite size during layout. I/flutter (26968): Another exception was thrown: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler object was given an infinite size during layout. I/flutter (26968): Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by Infinity pixels on the right.
         Reloaded 1 of 499 libraries in 1,060ms. I/flutter (26968): Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by Infinity pixels on the right.
```

Comment: The code appears to be cut while posting here, check once and update the question.

Comment: Have you tried giving `GestureDetector` a child?

Comment: good observation @mazei513

Comment: @dev-aentgs only this section of the project was throw error

Comment: @mazei513 no is that the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check out this example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Users'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _lights = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: 50,
        color: Colors.indigo,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
        child: Row(
          // cmainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,

          children: [
            Text(
              "For more information on ABC",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 10,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _lights = true;
                  });
                },
                child: Text(
                  'Click',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Change the styling according to you need and let me know if works.

Answer (score 0):

GestureDetector was causing the problem when i commented it, RenderFlex was able to get the right constrain